# Category index featured image

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails, archives

I wish to set a featured/header image for each of my category archive pages, how would I go about doing this without hard coding each category into the theme?

An example of the page is at http://keswickscouts.org/section/cubs

The code form header.php is

```
            <div id="main-image">
        <?php
            // Check to see if the header image has been removed
            $header_image = get_header_image();
            if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    if ( !is_404() && !is_attachment() ) { // Check if this is not 404 or attachment page
                        // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a post-thumbnail
                        if ( is_singular() && has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && ( $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' ) ) && $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else : ?>
                        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; } // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>
        </div><!-- end #main-image -->
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm seeing an issue where the "post-thumbnail" image size is probably not going to be as wide as the `HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH` (I'd change it to 'full') but otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You also might want to check the code for your 404 page - it says "use the search box above" but there's no search box!

Comment: I've reworded the question, hopefully it should make more sense. I've had no issues with the width but will have a look, and thanks for the heads up on the 404 page it is completely knackered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was; using the [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.mfields.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin to associate an image with each category, then to my theme's header.php, below the `<a>` line in the above code;

```
<?php 
            $image_id = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image-id', 0 );
            if ( is_category() && ! empty( $image_id )):
             print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '',  
                array(
                'image_size' => 'header'
            ) );
            else : ?>
```

And add `<?php endif; ?>` below the endif 'end check for featured...'

and defined the header image size in functions.php with

```
add_image_size( 'header', 960, 260, true );
```

Comment: How can I modify this to work on single.php? Just removing the `if ( is_category() )` doesn't work.